# Magento unrelated search results

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, search, ce-1.9.2.4

I have a problem in my site. I get too many unrelated results, and if I refresh cache it is fixed for a while. It seems like its search results of other people (or my previous searches). Is there a way to fix this?

Magento version 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Set the search type to 'Fulltext' in '*System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search*' and check if this solves the problem.

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: Reindex 'Catalog Search Index'

Comment: it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Set the search type to 'Combine (Like and Fulltext)' in 'System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search' and check if this solves the problem.

Please reindex after chnages.

Comment: it has been like this before.
Which index should I reindex?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please check how many attribute allow in Quick search.
Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes and check Attribute.

For testing only allow SKU and Name attribute in quick search and check the search result.

Comment: I have got Brand, description, meta_keywords, name, short_description, SKU. I happens occasionally so I can't check the result right away, and therefore I can't set the search only for SKU because I don't know when it will happen and I don't wanna limit the search for customers.